# Dump multidimensional tensor to file

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I have a multidimensional tensor and I want to dump it as a matrix to a file. Whats the best way to do this.

For now I have the following for a 4-dimensional tensor:

```
const tensorflow::TensorShape& tensor_shape = tensor.shape();
auto _tensor = tensor.tensor<float, 4>();
for(int i=0; i<tensor_shape.dim_size(0); i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<tensor_shape.dim_size(1); j++)
    {

        for(int k=0; k<tensor_shape.dim_size(2); k++)
        {
            for(int l=0; l<tensor_shape.dim_size(3); k++)
            {
               std::cout << _tensor(i,j,k,l) << std::endl; //right one
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However this is extremely slow.. is there a better and more efficient way to do this?

Comment: For improvement of already working code better ask at [SE Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions).

Comment: are you looping on the tensor in the right order? Can you just get a raw pointer to the data and dump it instead? Converting the data to ascii will always be slow and can lead to loss of precision.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher That does speed up but than i get a file with very long lines e.g.:      11.0165     -11.0151      8.70215     -8.70094      7.43365     -7.43253      8.76552     -8.76442      10.3197     -10.3186.....

Comment: `for(int l=0; l<tensor_shape.dim_size(3); k++)` -- You have `k++` when it should be `l++`.

Comment: If you have ascii output + a flush at each call, then yes, you will be very slow. And as Paul says, you have an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks @PaulMcKenzie that indeed did the job!

Comment: @AhmadRahimi There's probably some data access to the tensor... looping like this is not a good idea.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist Hmm I agree, but I can't seem to find a better option.. You have any idea?

Comment: @AhmadRahimi I'm not familiar with this library. But given it's written by experts, then it's definitely contiguous in memory, and there's definitely a way to access the internal data. Just like `std::vector::data()`. Use that to flatten it.